# Resizable div not resizing after adding text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used jQuery UI resizable function on div element. The resize function is not working after adding text to div .

```
  <div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
    Resizable div
   </div>
```

I have button to add text to div.

```
  <input type="button" name="add" value="Add text" id="add"> // onclick add text function
```

**after adding text to div ,it is no longer resizable.
Here is the jsfiddle link:**  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yu9RK/3/)

how to handle this event.
edit:
My requirement is adding completely new text. I don't want to append new text to previous text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use separate span for the **text** because the resize is working based on the following **divs** inside the **resizable** div

```
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
```

if you use `html()` it will replace these `divs`. So please try with the following

```
<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <span id="resizable-text">Resizable div</span>
   </div>
```

and in **js**

```
  var txt="This is dummy text";
        $("#add").click(function(){
        $("#resizable-text").html(txt);
        });
```

If you use append the text will append with existing text.

Answer (score 0):

Use `append` instead of `html`

```
var txt="This is dummy text";
$("#add").click(function(){
    $("#resizable").append(txt);
});
```